# Modifying a ggplot object gives Null error

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to modify a graph produced by [interaction library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interactions/index.html), which according to documentation is a ggplot object. Specifically, I want to modify the y axis limits.

```
library(interactions)

alpha = 5
w = 4
r = 4
wr = 4

w1 =  rnorm(1000,10,2)
r1 = rnorm(1000,10,2)
e = rnorm(1000,0,100)

y = alpha + w*w1 + r*r1 + wr*w1*r1 + e

m =  lm(y~ w1 + r1 + w1*r1)

p<- johnson_neyman(m,pred=r1,modx=w1,mod.range = c(0,100))

#element which is ggplot object
q <- p[3]
```

Based on search of past questions, I tried

```
q <- q +ylim(c(0,1000))
```

which gives "NULL".

Also tried

```
ggplot_build(q)
```

Which gives

> Error in UseMethod("ggplot_build") :    no applicable method for
> 'ggplot_build' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: Try `q <- p[[3]]` or `q <- p$plot`, i.e. use `[[` instead of `[`.

Comment: See e.g. [The difference between bracket \[ \] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Comment: @stefan already pointed out the suitable subsetting operator = double brackets . Here's some detail about the meaning of single vs. double brackets: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#subset-single

Comment: You can do: `p$plot + ylim(c(0, 1000))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments,

```
q <- p[[3]]
```

or

```
q <- p$plot
```

solved it.